# Use of undeclared type error

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-login

I trying add fb login, but just this error, How can i fixed it ?

[image]

```
func application(application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: protocol<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id>) -> Bool {
        var handled: Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey], annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
        // Add any custom logic here.
        return handled
    }
```

Comment: what version of Swift are you running ? I believe URL is only available in Swift 3

Comment: oh i guess swiftify convert 3 , i trying 2